# Dos select html required

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

Tengo un formulario con dos selects y los dos son "required". Quiero que se haga el submit al cambiar el segundo, pero le he puesto onchange="submit()" y no funciona, hace submit aunque no se haya seleccionado ninguna opción en el primero. ¿Alguien tiene una solución?

```html
<form id="formulario" action="Servlet" method="post">
  <select name="idsociedad" id="idsociedad" required>
    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="opcion1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="opcion2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="opcion3">Opción 3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="ano" id="ano" onchange="submit()" required>
    <option value="">Seleccione el año</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: De todas formas ya hace submit() no? es decir, almenos si ejecutas tu código esta buscando servlet.

Comment: Sí, pero necesito que se escojan opciones en ambos select obligatoriamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías asignarle un listener a ambos `select` y que cuando estos cambien, ejecuten una función que revise sus valores, si no están vacios hará `submit`.

Este es el código:

```js
function submitForm() {
  var sociedad = $('#idsociedad').val();
  var anio = $('#ano').val();

  if (sociedad !== '' && anio !== '') {
    // $('#formulario').submit();
    console.log('Submiting form at: ' + new Date());
  };
};

$('body').on('change', '#idsociedad', submitForm);
$('body').on('change', '#ano', submitForm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario" action="Servlet" method="post">
  <select name="idsociedad" id="idsociedad" required>
    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="opcion1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="opcion2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="opcion3">Opción 3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="ano" id="ano" required>
    <option value="">Seleccione el año</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Este código crea una funcion para comprobar cuando hacer submit, una vez modificas el select de año. Hará submit cuando el select de sociedad tenga un valor seleccionado.

```js
function checkSubmitConditions() {
  if ($('#formulario #idsociedad').prop('selectedIndex') > 0) {
    $('#formulario').submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario" action="Servlet" method="post">
    <select name="idsociedad" id="idsociedad" required>
        <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
        <option value="opcion1">Opción 1</option>
        <option value="opcion2">Opción 2</option>
        <option value="opcion3">Opción 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="ano" id="ano" onchange="checkSubmitConditions()" required>
        <option value="">Seleccione el año</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Esto hace exactamente lo mismo que su código.

Comment: El problema de este código es que si el usuario primero escoge el año y despues una opcion del primer select no hace submit.

Comment: @blonfu pero el OP no esta `preguntando por ninguna comprobacion del primer select ¿no?. Es decir, lo único que dice es que necesita hacer submit cuando cambia el segundo. Cosa que ya hace su código.

Comment: @David Exactamente, como dice blonfu, "Quiero que se haga el submit al cambiar el segundo." ya lo haces y es lo que pides. Aclara mejor la pregunta entonces :).

Comment: Cuando digo que los dos son "required" quiero decir que los dos selects quiero que sean obligatorios.

Comment: Si, cierto, entonces, la respuesta sería la correcta. Pero @David redacta algo mejor la pregunta :)

Comment: Quizás se podíra añadir el mismo onchange a los dos selects. Con eso nos aseguramos que se ha seleccionado algo en los dos selects.

Comment: Vamos a ver, eso soluciona el problema que preguntas.. modificaló como te de la gana. Hace submit cuando cambia el segundo y el primero ha sido seleccionado, que es lo que estás preguntando.

Comment: Recordad ir borrando los mensajes obsoletos para no *ensuciar* la publicacion heheh si quereis, puedo crearos una sala de chat. Un saludo

Comment: yo borro los mios

Answer (score 0):

Pueden intentar hacer esto. Adiciono el evento del change al combo dos, y valido que se haya seleccionado algo en el combo 1 antes de hacer el submit, sino, mostramos una alerta

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    Change_Select();
});
function Change_Select() {
    $("#ano").change(function () {
        /*Validamos si el cambio es para seleccionar un valor*/
        let val = $("#idsociedad").val();        
        if (val.length > 0 && val != null) {          
            $("#formulario").submit();
        }else{
          alert("Debe seleccionar un valor en el primer combo para poder enviar el combo.")
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario" action="Servlet" method="post">
  <select name="idsociedad" id="idsociedad" required>
    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="opcion1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="opcion2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="opcion3">Opción 3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="ano" id="ano" required>
    <option value="">Seleccione el año</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

En vez de vincular tu función en línea en el HTML hazlo luego a través de JS, ya que el principal problema que vas a tener es que se va a intentar enviar directamente al action que has indicado, para evitar esto utilizamos el método [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

```js
// Variables 

const societySelect = document.querySelector('#idsociedad');
const yearSelect = document.querySelector('#ano');

// Funciones

function submitOnChangeYear(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Esta línea es la importante
  if (societySelect.value === '' || yearSelect.value === '') {
    console.warn('Para enviar el formulario la sociedad y el año son obligatorios.');
  } else {
    console.log('...Aquí envias tu formulario con AJAX...');
  }
}

// Eventos

yearSelect.onchange = submitOnChangeYear;
```

```html
<form id="formulario" action="Servlet" method="post">
  <select name="idsociedad" id="idsociedad" required>
    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="opcion1">Opción 1</option>
    <option value="opcion2">Opción 2</option>
    <option value="opcion3">Opción 3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="ano" id="ano" required>
    <option value="">Seleccione el año</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
  </select>
</form>
```